# Is it possible to write classes using functions in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, higher-order-functions

Is it possible to write classes using functions in Scala, like one would do in Javascript ?

Comment: What does `write classes using functions` mean?

Comment: As in implementing classes and objects using functions and closures.

Comment: You can only write a class in Scala using some sort of an input source like a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use any function as a constructor? No. Can you [use closures as "poor man's objects"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent)? Yes. But what you get in this way is not called a class in Scala.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Actually my question was related to one of Martin Odersky's video lectures. Where he asked whether it is possible to implement objects using higher order functions.

Comment: Each function is under the hood optimized to the object with `apply` method. So something like this `def addOne(x: Int): Int = x + 1` will be treated as `object addOne { def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 1 }` keep in mind this is a very rough example. This is the way that Scala achieves treating functions like objects but I am not sure whether this is what you are asking for.