# Can objects be implemented in terms of higher order functions?

Tags: scala

Can we implement one concept in terms of other ?

```
Objects in terms of higher order functions?
Higher order functions in terms of objects?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write classes using functions in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433112/is-it-possible-to-write-classes-using-functions-in-scala).

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

> Objects in terms of higher order functions?

If your language has records, then you can implement objects as a record of closures closing over a common environment. In fact, that's exactly how objects are implemented in ECMAScript. (In ECMAScript, records are confusingly called *objects*, though.)

If you don't have records, or you subscribe to the message-oriented paradigm of OO, you can use a selector function instead, which takes the "message" as a parameter and returns a closure based on the message. This is how pretty much all [object systems in Scheme](http://community.schemewiki.org/?object-systems) work, for example [Oleg Kiselyov's *Purely-functional Object-Oriented System*](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/#pure-oo).

> Higher order functions in terms of objects?

In fact, [Scala implements functions using objects](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html).

- An object with a single method is isomorphic to a function.
- An object with a single method and some instance variables is isomorphic to a closure.
- An object with a single method that takes an object with a single method as parameter or returns an object with a single method is isomorphic to a higher-order function.

That's *exactly* how functions are implemented in Scala (with a method named `apply`), Ruby (with a method named `call`), `Python` (with a method named `__call__`), and Java (as instances of a so-called SAM interface, an interface with a Single Abstract Method).